# Error while trying to dual boot Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 15.10

Being specific, 
When I was trying to install Ubuntu 15.10, my other operating system remains undetected.
"Multiple OS detected"
But still it wont let me dual boot my Windows 10 and Ubuntu.
Please help.

Comment: You mean you have installed Ubuntu but you don't get boot menu for choosing to which OS you want to boot?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to go over it myself and was able to dual both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10 by the following method :

In Windows 10, 
Open up partition manager and dislocate some space out of your windows partition for Ubuntu(don't really write anything).
Then boot into Ubuntu 15.10 installation and click

> do something else

After that select the space you just cleared up and format it as EXT4(Linux file-system).
It will peacefully install.
PEACE!